# I want to destroy data from relationships but I can't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want user to remove group that user attending groups by removing groupings.
So, I tried write below the code , but when run leave action , it happen error that 
`Unknown key: group_id`.But  I don't know how to deal with it . Please some help.
Thanks in advance.

GroupingsController.rb

```
def leave
  @user = current_user
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  @user.remove(@group)
  redirect_to :back , notice: "Destroy!"
end
```

User.rb

```
has_many :groups, :through => :groupings,:source => :group

def remove(group)
  groupings.find_by_group_id(:group_id => group).destroy
end

# attend method is work correctly.
def attend(group)
  groupings.create(:group_id => group)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already specified that you're using group_id (by saying `find_by_group_id`) - so you don't need to specify it again by passing it as a 'key' (eg `:group_id =>`)

So your code should just be

```
def remove(group)
  groupings.find_by_group_id(group.id).destroy
end
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a easy miss.I feel a little shame.

Comment: happens to the best of us ;) You can "accept" my answer if it solved your problem, by clicking on the "tick" mark to the left of it.